# Making bash script to pull in all git subdirectories. Feel like my bash script is not very well-optimized

Tags: bash, git

I was getting tired of having to run "git pull" for every directory that I have that pulls from a git repository. So I made this script. I'm not very experienced at bash (first script written is this). So I think my method might be a bit dumb, or can be done in a better way. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e;
current_dir=$PWD

# check if argument has been supplied
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Please pass a directory";
    exit 1;
# declare $PASSED variable as the supplied argument
else
    PASSED=$1;
fi

# Check if passed argument is a directory
if [ -d "${PASSED}" ]; then
    git_directory=false;
    # for every directory with .git in it
    find . -name ".git"|while read fname; do
        #TODO: FIND BETTER WAY FOR THIS
        git_directory=true;
        cd "$current_dir/$fname";
        cd ..;
        echo "Pulling from remote repo";
        git pull origin master;
        cd "$current_dir";
    done
    if ! "$git_directory"; then
        echo "No git directories were found, are you sure you gave the correct directory?";
        exit 1;
    fi

else
    echo "Please pass a directory";
    exit 1;
fi
```

I feel the part under "#TODO: FIND BETTER WAY FOR THIS" is pretty badly written and there's probably a better way for it.

Anyone got any tips?

Comment: `cd "$fname/.."` in a subshell would be simpler. Using a subshell means there is no need to `cd` back explicitly after.

Answer (score 2):

```
find "$1" -name ".git" -type d -execdir git pull upstream master \;
```

avoids issues with `while read` on things which might contain a newline or a backslash.

You are not using the variable `$PASSED` for anything. (Avoid uppercase for your private variables anyway.)

Forcing all your projects to have their primary remote to be `upstream` and to be on branch `master` is a very simplistic assumption which will come back and bite you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `find` do all the work for you:

```
find "$1" -name .git -print -execdir git pull origin master \;
```